# How to find the coefficient of $x^3y^5$ in the expression $(1+xy+y^2)^n$

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

We are given the expression $(1+xy+y^2)^n$ where $n$ is positive integer. We are required to find the coefficient of $x^3y^5$ in the expansion of the given expression.

I know how to expand a binom to certain power, if it was $(xy+y^2)^n$ then $n = 4$ and the coefficient would be $\binom{4}{1}(xy)^3(y^2)^1$, but I'm not sure how to solve this when we have expression with three terms.

Comment: Note that $$(a+b+c)^n = \sum \frac{n!}{i! j! k!}a^{i}b^{j}c^{k},$$ where the sum is taken over all ordered triples of non-negative integers $(i,j,k)$ such that $i+j+k=n$ (there are $\binom{n+2}{2}$ such triples, and hence terms in this sum). You can read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_expansion and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem for more information.

Answer (score 2):

We may have

- $x^3y^5=(xy)^3y^2$

then by [**trinomial expansion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_expansion)

$$(1+xy+y^2)^n =\ldots+ \frac{5!}{1!2!3!}(xy)^3y^2+\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

The coefficient of $x^3$ in $$(xy+(1+y^2))^n$$ will be $$\binom n3y^3(1+y^2)^{n-3}$$

So, we need the coefficient of $y^{5-3}$ in $$(1+y^2)^{n-3}$$ which is $\binom{n-3}1$